# Google contacts api parsing xml and get contact title

Tags: php, xml

I'm using oauth 2.0 and I trying to use **contacts google api**.

```
$url = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?v=2.0&max-results='.$max_results.'&oauth_token='.$accesstoken;
```

Result of this I have there: `$xmlresponse` result is fine and good (it means that not have issues)

```
$xml =  new SimpleXMLElement($xmlresponse);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('atom', 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind');
$result = $xml->xpath('//atom:title');

var_dump($xml);
var_dump($result);
foreach ($result as $title) {
  echo $title->attributes()->address . "<br>";
}
```

I want to get title contact (in `var_dump($xml)` it is visible as 'title') but $result is empty

*Question:*

**1) How to get title contact from this xml response ?**

Comment: please post a working minimum example of that XML. You might want to look for namespaces and XML here on SO